# Random variable of twice another random variable

Tags: probability

If Y is a random variable with a mean $\mu$ and a standard deviation, $\sigma$, how do I calculate W if W = 2Y? Is it just $2\mu$ and $2\sigma$?

Comment: Do you know properties like linearity of expectation?

Comment: No. But from what I understand below, all that was said was that the constant can be taken out of the formula. Is that all that changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E(X) = mu

E(W) = c*E(X) = c*mu

VAR(W) = VAR(c*X) = c^2VAR(X)

SD(W) = c*SD(X)